# How to open XML results automatically in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssms

It might sound insane what I am asking but I said to give it a try. I have the following statements that create a table and open a XML file from a location.

```
CREATE TABLE Ts (IntCol int, XmlCol xml);  
GO  

INSERT INTO Ts(XmlCol)  
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(  
   BULK 'C:\Users\caf\Desktop\EEEEE\StoreDocument.xml',  
   SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;  
 GO
```

However, when I use `SELECT XmlCol FROM TS` the results are like a link and if I click on it, in a new window the content within the `XML` file are displayed. So far so good and correct.

Is there any way that after the `select` statement is executed somehow to auto open the results in a new tab without having to click myself? Thanks

Comment: @TT - yes. Can you please tell/show how?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know...

If you chose "output to grid" (that's the case, where you'd get the "link") SSMS expects a multi-column result. Only in cases where the XML is the only column, this might work.

But still SSMS expects many rows. Only in cases where your XML is a scalar answer (=one single value) this might make sense.

But SQL and SSMS support for *set-based* thinking. Scalar values are *procedural thinking*.

If you know, that your XML is the one and only response, you could use "output to text", but this is not the same...

So, I'm sorry, I think you will have to perform that click manually :-D